# Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
Here is what I'm trying to : I'm using an rplidar, arduino connected to Raspberry with ROS kinetic, to do autonomous mapping and navigation.

First, i run the rplidar with

```
roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch
```

then , slam mapping with

```
roslaunch rplidar_ros view_slam.launch
```

then  I used hector_exploration with

```
roslaunch hector_exploration_node exploration_planner.launch
```

Final, to publish the cmd_vel topic I run

```
rosrun hector_exploration_controller simple_exploration_controller
```

My question, when I try to send cmd_vel values to Arduino through this code below

```
#include <ArduinoHardware.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

ros::Publisher pub("cmd_vel", &msg);

void setup()
{
 nh.initNode();
 nh.advertise(pub);
} void loop()
{

pub.publish(&msg);
nh.spinOnce();
}
```

Once I run this code on arduino, my rplidar stop spinning and give me this error message

```
[ WARN] [1532545086.000125786]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1532545086.000656149]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298630/reason-given-for-shutdown:-%5Bnew-node-registered-with-same-name%5D/) by [hamzh.albar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36205/hamzh.albar@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Node names need to be unique. You have more than one node with the same name. Make sure that every node name is unique and you won't get this behavior.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamzh.albar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36205/hamzh.albar@gmail.com/) on 2018-07-25**:
Make sense, in this case the only node should be `cmd_vel` since everything working fine before running the arduino code ?
If so, how can I change the node name and send to arduino in the same time ??

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-25**:
It depends on which nodes are giving you trouble. The full error should say what the name of the node is.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-26**:
@hamzh.albar@gmail.com if this answered your question, please click on the check mark to mark this answer as correct.